# Why isn't there a round()-type function that returns an int?

Tags: c, rounding, c99

The C standard library, [N1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) defines a bunch of rounding functions. There are basically two "complete" families,

- rint:

  ```
  double rint(double x);
  float rintf(float x);
  long double rintl(long double x);
  // The rint functions round their argument to an integer value
  //  in floating-point format, using the current rounding direction

  long int lrint(double x);
  long int lrintf(float x);
  long int lrintl(long double x);
  long long int llrint(double x);
  long long int llrintf(float x);
  long long int llrintl(long double x);
  // The lrint and llrint functions round their argument 
  //  to the nearest integer value, rounding according to the current
  //  rounding direction. If the rounded value is outside the range of
  //  the return type, the numeric result is unspecified and a domain
  //  error or range error may occur. *
  ```
- round:

  ```
  double round(double x);
  float roundf(float x);
  long double roundl(long double x);
  // The round functions round their argument to the nearest integer value 
  //  in floating-point format, rounding halfway cases away from zero, 
  //  regardless of the current rounding direction.

  long int lround(double x);
  long int lroundf(float x);
  long int lroundl(long double x);
  long long int llround(double x);
  long long int llroundf(float x);
  long long int llroundl(long double x);
  // The lround and llround functions round their argument to the nearest
  //  integer value, rounding halfway cases away from zero, regardless of the
  //  current rounding direction. If the rounded value is outside the range of 
  //  the return type, the numeric result is unspecified and 
  //  a domain error or range error may occur.
  ```

However, there is apparently no variation that behaves like `round()` or `rint()` and returns an `int`, e.g.:

```
int iround(double d);
int iroundf(float f);
int iroundl(long double l);

int irint(double d);
int irintf(float f);
int irintl(long double l);
```

I understand that one concern may be that `int` can not express a properly wide range of values, but the same argument could very well be made for `long int` (maximum value is ~10^19 for a `long int`, vs ~10^128 for a `float`).
Does anyone know why the standard does not define such rounding functions ?

Comment: My guess is that it's because they're trivially equivalent to a `round()` followed by a type conversion.

Comment: Ok, but then, what you're saying also applies to `lround()`, right ? So why were those put in the standard ?

Comment: Well if you really want a function like that , write it yourself.
But the real reason is probably is that the int can't store as big numbers as float or double, if it would return int, it could mess up your application, or even crash it. Because of this the application will be more safer. But i'm curious too.

Comment: Hadn't the `ll*` functions been added later? So the `l*` functions needed to stay around for compatibility reasons?

Comment: @newboyhun: I don't even need a function like that ;) It's really just curiosity. As for `int` being too small, you can say the same about other int types, so I'm not convinced, even if it's the best explanation so far.

Comment: maybe because there could be an overflow....not sure about the length of the mantisas for each type...

Comment: @alk - (re the `ll*` functions being added later) -- That's exactly right. The `l*` functions were in C90. C99 added `long long`, and hence the new rounding functions.

Comment: Why do I feel so old now ...?-) @DavidHammen

Comment: It is not a problem on platforms, where `int` equals `long int`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Why isn't there a round()-type function that returns an int?

Because the `l*`-functions cover the `i*` functions' functionallity.

So the follow-up question is:

**Why do we have `l*` functions as we also have `ll*`functions?**

The answer is that C99 added the new `long long` data type, accompanied by the related new library functions.

For rounding integers C90 already provided the

- `lrint*()`
- `lround*()`

functions which needed to stay around for compatiblitiy reasons.

With the new C99 data type `long long` the new functions

- `llrint*()`
- `llround*()`

were introduced.

Comment: +1 Nice line of reasoning. Note: Maybe C should add a FP --> intmax_t and be done with it.